# webcam video not rendered in web page

Tags: javascript, html

i want to access my webcam with `getUserMedia` in javascript.

```js
var video = document.querySelector("#webcam");

// ask permission
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.oGetUserMedia;

// if the user allowing
if (navigator.getUserMedia) {

  navigator.getUserMedia({
    video: true
  }, handleVideo, videoError);
}

// this function will executed when the user allowing the permission
function handleVideo(stream) {
  video.srcObject = stream;
}

// this function will executed when the user block the permission
function videoError(e) {
  // do something
  alert("error")
}
```

```html
<video id="webcam" autoplay="true"></video>
```

when i allowing the permission, it show the error alert. and i'm using https. does anyone can help me ? any answer would be appreciated it. thanks in advance

Comment: Well what are the details contained within the error object, `e`? Have you `console.log`'d it?

Comment: it say `DomException: Could not start video source` @Utkanos

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure your webcam is activated in the computer? On windows in can be necessary to autorize access to the microphone to be start video.

Comment: yes, i just try a few website that provide the demo with the same code that i used, and it works. btw i run in ubuntu

Comment: I see that navigator.getUserMedia is depreciated, did you try with navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia

Comment: it still has the same error, i have no idea. but my webcam works fine

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I know but I wasn't allowed to post a comment Utkanos